# What to expect in the `Authorization` header if I'm using an API key?

Tags: http-headers, authorization, api-key

I'm making a stateless micro-service that receives an empty `POST` to `/`. I need some way to secure it that's stateless, so I'm making up an API key in an `.env.local` file and using this API key to "authenticate" my `POST` requests.

With the `Authorization` header, there's multiple standards on how to use tokens

- `Basic`, which uses username+password in base64
- `Bearer`, which is usually a jwt or another oauth token that replaces a username+password that's negotiated beforehand

But that token is none of that. It's just a plain-text password in the form of `c992bc6c-6d0c-40b6-bf95-f42117209640` that can be rotated whenever.

So what "type" of authorization is it? Is there some kind of standard to authenticate with API keys? Or am I looking at the wrong header in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

[Bearer tokens](https://oauth.net/2/bearer-tokens/) were devised in scope of the OAuth2 standard but later evolved to more than that. It's a common practice to use it for any non-cookie-based tokens as a general mechanism for API token-based authentication.

[Api Security in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/api-security-in-action) is a good treatment of this topic, in particular chapter 5.2.2 (Bearer authentication scheme)